# Proposal for MySQL database structure for sensor data (sanity check)

Tags: mysql, database

I have a network of sensor units that will be polled or pushing (undecided) data to a server fairly regularly. Each unit has some static properties, and some time varying readings that I want to record. My primary concern is that the following sketch is actually possible to implement:

```
NODE Table -> stores time varying values per node. I would also like to add a column to store references to the relevant row in the NODES table
Headings --> TimeStamp | Voltage | Current | Temp | Humidity | RoundRobinIndex

NODES Table -> stores static properties about each node
Headings --> Serial | Latitude | Longitude | IP | OtherProps | Pointer to NODE table
```

This is my first experience with MySQL (and database admin in general), so I wanted to check that this is a reasonable approach before immersing myself in MySQL. I'm open to suggestions for other databasing tools or approaches too.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need a node ID column in the `NODE` table, and I'd rename that `NODE` table to something like `NODE_DATA` so it's a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building what is known as a relational database. What database management system you use is entirely your choice; they all have their pros and cons, but generally speaking MySQL works best with PHP (in my experience).

That aside, in order for you to reference the information in the `NODES` table, you'll want to create a `Node_ID` column in the `NODE` table.

```
NODE Table -> stores time varying values per node. I would also like to add a column to store references to the relevant row in the NODES table
Headings --> Node_ID | TimeStamp | Voltage | Current | Temp | Humidity | RoundRobinIndex
```

Setting `Node_ID` as the primary key (that is the column that allows you to uniquely identify a row in your table), you can reference this as a foreign key (a primary key from another table, in this instance the `NODE` table) in the `NODES` table.

```
NODES Table -> stores static properties about each node
Headings --> Serial | Latitude | Longitude | IP | OtherProps | Node_ID
```

To retrieve the data from the `NODES` table, you could have an SQL statement as follows:

```
SELECT NODE.Node_ID, NODE.TimeStamp, NODES.Serial
FROM NODE
-- Either:
INNER JOIN NODES ON NODE.Node_ID = NODES.Node_ID
WHERE NODE.Node_ID = 2;
-- Or:
WHERE NODE.Node_ID = NODES.Node_ID
AND NODE.Node_ID = 2;
```

This will select the `Node_ID`, `TimeStamp` and `Serial` from their respective tables for the record whose Node_ID value equals to 2.

Comment: Thanks mate, very thorough :)